# Error Message on custom button to replicate validation rule

Tags: javascript, custom-button, validation-rule

I am using a custom button and am having issues with the error message displayed to the user.

The error message is kicking in because the "service_lifecycle_status__c" field is not set to "Beta", however it doesn't say that, it basically says my class has failed along with a load of technical jargon the user won't understand.

How would I build something into my code, that evaluates whether or not the record has the field status set to Beta, and if it hasn't display an error message saying "This record cannot be converted until the service lifecycle status is changed to Beta"?

Below is my class that sits behind the javascript button.

```
global class ProductAction {
WebService static String convertToService(Id product2) {
    string result; // Return a string telling us if this worked or not
    Id currentProfile = UserInfo.getProfileId();  // Get the current user profile Id
    Id CurrentUser = UserInfo.getUserId(); // Get the current user Id

    Set<Id> allowedProfiles = new Set<Id>(); // Create a new set to profile Ids
    for (Profile p: [SELECT Id, Name FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'System Administrator']) {// Get the System Administrator profile
        allowedProfiles.add(p.Id); // Add them to the set
    }

    Set<Id> allowedUsers = new Set<Id>(); // Create a new set to store User Ids
    for (User u: [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Id = '005w0000004j93kAAA' OR Id = '005w0000004Noi6']) {//Select Joy Palmer and Andy McGregor Id's and select Jeremey Sharp and Mark O'Leary once they're in SF}
        allowedUsers.add(u.Id);// Add them to the set
    }
    Product2 prod = [SELECT Convert_to_Service_catalogue__c, R_D_Service_Owner__r.id , Project_Owner__r.Id From Product2 WHERE Id = :product2]; // Get the product

    if( //If...
        (currentUser == prod.R_D_Service_Owner__r.id) || // They own it
        (currentUser == prod.Project_Owner__r.id) || // They own it 
        (allowedProfiles.contains(currentProfile)) || //They're a system admin
        (allowedUsers.contains(currentUser)) // They're a specific user

      ) {
            //Do stuff!
            prod.Convert_to_Service_Catalogue__c = true;

            UPDATE prod;

            result = 'Success!';


        }   
    else {// Otherwise...
          // Do nothing
          result = 'A full service catalogue could not be generated. This is because the lifecycle status is not set to Beta, or because you dont have permission to convert this record';
        }  
       // Return a message
       return result;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've pulled the lifecycle status field into the soql query. And then added the status into my if statement, so it's not showing a user friendly error message.

```
 global class ProductAction {
WebService static String convertToService(Id product2) {
    string result; // Return a string telling us if this worked or not
    Id currentProfile = UserInfo.getProfileId();  // Get the current user profile Id
    Id CurrentUser = UserInfo.getUserId(); // Get the current user Id

    Set<Id> allowedProfiles = new Set<Id>(); // Create a new set to profile Ids
    for (Profile p: [SELECT Id, Name FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'System Administrator']) {// Get the System Administrator profile
        allowedProfiles.add(p.Id); // Add them to the set
    }

    Set<Id> allowedUsers = new Set<Id>(); // Create a new set to store User Ids
    for (User u: [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Id = '005w0000004j93kAAA' OR Id = '005w0000004Noi6']) {//Select Joy Palmer and Andy McGregor Id's and select Jeremey Sharp and Mark O'Leary once they're in SF}
        allowedUsers.add(u.Id);// Add them to the set
    }
    Product2 prod = [SELECT Lifecycle_Status__c, Convert_to_Service_catalogue__c, R_D_Service_Owner__r.id , Project_Owner__r.Id From Product2 WHERE Id = :product2]; // Get the product

    if( //If...
        (prod.Lifecycle_Status__c == 'Beta') &&
        ((currentUser == prod.R_D_Service_Owner__r.id) || // They own it
        (currentUser == prod.Project_Owner__r.id) || // They own it 
        (allowedProfiles.contains(currentProfile)) || //They're a system admin
        (allowedUsers.contains(currentUser))) // They're a specific user

      ) {
            //Do stuff!
            prod.Convert_to_Service_Catalogue__c = true;

            UPDATE prod;

            result = 'Success!';


        }   
    else {// Otherwise...
          // Do nothing
          result = 'A full service catalogue could not be generated. This is because the lifecycle status is not set to Beta, or because you dont have permission to convert this record';
        }  
       // Return a message
       return result;
    }

}
```